# Book about a man fired because his hyphenated last name was too long

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read a paperback book no later than the 1976 (I strongly believe that I read it before I graduated high school, possibly years before). I think I bought it from a garage sale, so it may have been even older. The book was in English.

- The setting was modern day (for its time), and the main character
  worked at (I believe) a company that made plastics. He was a white-collar worker, I believe he was a
  scientist. He had a very long hyphenated last name.
- At the start of the story, the company bought a new computer or database for human resources. His boss
  called him into his office, and explained that the new computer was unable to store his last name.
  The company may have been willing to work with an abbreviated last name, but I'm not sure, but the
  character refused to do so.
- Because of this, he was fired.
- The main character was angry and wanted to destroy the company. He developed some sort of mold or
  fungus that ate plastic. He released this.
- At some point I believe his previous secretary joined him in his crusade. I believe she was an older
  woman, but that may have been a product of my age. I think that she was the one that used the phrase
  "It's a hyphenated name!" as a slogan.
- I think that he won, and eventually released a form of his mold that would destroy plastics in dumps
  and make it so that future plastics would have a more limited lifetime.

This wasn't a particularly good book, and I don't remember the author's name. The cover was, I believe, reddish with some sort of machinery on it, but I don't know for sure.

I do not believe this is *Mutant 59: The Plastic Eaters*.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

[***The Man Whose Name Wouldn't Fit (Or, The Case of Cartwright-Chickering)***](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?611489) by **Theodore Tyler.** First published way, way back in 1968, when the whole idea of having a mainframe computer start handling a large corporation's payroll records, etc., probably using lots of "punch cards" in the process, was considered cutting-edge technology, and nobody had ever seen or heard of the idea of the company having hundreds of computers placed on the desks of the individual employees. (Since Apples and other varieties of "affordable personal computers," as we understand them today, had not yet been invented!)

[image: Cover of book] [image: Title page of book]

I checked out a copy from a library, decades ago. The title character's name is Arthur Cartwright-Chickering. The plot goes as you describe (as far as I can remember), and a review on Amazon describes it thus:

> Anyway, Mr. Cartwright-Chickering stumbled across a way to fight back
> against The Machine: a mold with a taste for computer tape, cultivated
> in dilute grape juice. This discovery can be chalked up to his nephews
> or grandsons having filled their water pistols with grape juice
> (before their mother caught them and made them dump them out), a
> missing plug, and a bit of moldy soap used to plug the gun...

I believe the computer software in question could only handle employee surnames of **20** characters or less. With the hyphen in the middle, the main character's surname was a whopping **21** characters, and so his name *just missed* fitting neatly into the necessary spot in the computer's database. He was the only person on the payroll whose name created such a problem. From the viewpoint of the senior executives, it just wasn't worth the hassle of paying someone to reprogram things to accommodate him alone. (Again, this was over half a century ago. Things have changed a bit.)

I seem to recall one of the executives saying approvingly that one of the secretaries on the payroll had a perfect name: Ann Pym. Three characters in the first name; three characters in the surname; making the whole thing very concise. The attitude seemed to be: "Why can't all our employees do it that way?" In fact, Ann Pym was *very sympathetic* to Arthur's predicament, as I recall. (I'm not sure if she was also Arthur's own secretary, whom you mentioned above. It's been too long.)

[Here's a link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0006BUEKE) to an Amazon page for the book. Apparently the text has never been converted into a Kindle e-book, so if you want to refresh your memory, you may have to order a secondhand copy of a paperback or hardback edition, or you could check it out in ePub or PDF format from the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/manwhosenamewoul00tyle/) or in hardcopy from a conventional library.

Comment: FWIW, not seeing that this had been solved, I started posting an answer based on me finding it with `novel man fired "hyphenated name" "too long" plastics`

Comment: "Things have changed a bit." Not so much. https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: @shoover Some of those "falsehoods" can be legally mandated (e.g. that names can only consist of the 26 characters of the English alphabet). I think that Elon Musk ran afoul of that one with the name of his kid.

Comment: @nick012000 Apparently, you mean “can be legally mandated in a certain country”. The falsehood collection is about the entire world, where most companies want to make business today. Trying to store the customer names of world-wide business into a database made by programmers who can’t think beyond the borders of their country, is exactly what it is all about.

Comment: These comments were getting long, so I've [moved them all to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108568/discussion-on-answer-by-lorendiac-book-about-a-man-fired-because-his-hyphenated). Mostly consisting of real-life anecdotes about similar situations; if anyone has more of those, please go and post them in the chatroom :-)

Comment: AD (Windows) usernames have a maximum limit of 20 characters, oh how times have cha... wait what?

Comment: @shoover 10 years ago, together with a couple of colleagues, we pushed management to make that article mandatory reading for ANYONE in our company that has to deal with names and name-storage. (Programmers, HRM, FCM, Finance & Accounting, Logistics, etc.). And it is not just the names of people. Address information (street, city, etc.) is just as bad.

Comment: This answer should be edited to include the pink dots in the book's title.  Also, the title is properly spelled in ALL-CAPS.

Comment: It is naïve to assume that English uses only 26 alphabetic characters

Comment: @Nat the normal convention is that the "correct" title of a book is on the title page, not the cover, if they disagree - the pink dots and ALL CAPS are just a stylistic choice to use a "computery font" (& plenty of books capitalise their title on the cover). The form as given is not wrong.

Comment: Is it intention or irony that the [Archive's URL ending](https://archive.org/details/manwhosenamewoul00tyle/) `manwhosenamewoul00tyle` is 22 characters long?

Comment: This has recently become the most upvoted Answer I've ever posted on this site -- and it's hard to see why it gets so much more attention than the average. Is it just because the question and the answer touch upon fears of computerized bureaucracies grinding up "the little guy" in the gears for reasons that are no fault of his?

Comment: @Andrew When I saw Nat's criticism of the way I typed out the title, I was inclined to think it was deliberately tongue-in-cheek -- a joke meant to amuse. (I mean, have you ever tried to type out a string of text that will include some cute little pink dots in the finished product?)

Comment: oh, I apologise @Nat  - definitely missed the joke, sorry!